# How to remove old versions of media files from a git repository

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a Git repository with several huge media files (images and audio files). Several versions of these media files have been successively commited to the repo. The files are successively refined versions of the same assets, and they have the same name.

I want to keep only the latest version in the Git repository, because it is becoming too big.
What is the simplest way to do this?
How can I propagate these changes correctly to the upstream repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a script ([github gist here](https://gist.github.com/kevinwright/a3d2efe2ce6ca48825ce)) to remove a selection of unwanted folders from the entire history of a git repo, or to delete all but the latest version of a folder.

It's hard-coded to assume that all git repositories are in `~/repos`, but that's easy to change.  It should also be easy to adapt to work with individual files.

Comment: Funny thing is... I wrote that script after first  checking on SO (and on this question) to see if there was a pre-existing solution :)

Answer (score 26):

*Old thread but in case someone else stumbles along here…*

GitHub & Bitbucket both recommend using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

See:
[GitHub: Remove Sensitive Data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)
[Bitbucket: Reduce Repository Size](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/reduce-repository-size-321848262.html) & 
[Bitbucket: Maintaining a Git Repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/maintaining-a-git-repository-321848291.html)

Example to remove files over 1 Megabyte, as well as jpgs, pngs and mp3s that are not in HEAD:

```
# First get the latest bfg.jar, then:
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
$ java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M --delete-files '*.{jpg,png,mp3}' some-big-repo.git
$ cd some-big-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ git push
```

Note: now you've pushed the updated revs, the remote repository should also run it's `git gc` …else you won't see the size reduction. (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782154/3419541)

Finally, *re-clone* the repository to be sure that you don't accidentally re-commit the old media file blobs.

Comment: for the last command I needed to do `git push --force origin <branch name, in my case master>` (it otherwise prompted me to re-integrate all the remote changes I had just removed--I think--from the local repo). Also, I was silly and didn't realize that the git clone isn't necessary if I already have an up-to-date local clone of a repo :p

Answer (score 10):

Check the section on 'Removing Objects' in the chapter [Maintenance and Data Recovery](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) in the ProGit book. It provides steps about how to go about removing objects from the git repo. But be warned though that it is destructive.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as accepted for now, as the chapter you linked seems the most detailed, straightforward and easy to understand explanation.

If I had to remark anything, it seems that the information in the chapter focuses on removing a file that was committed and removed after that.

What I was asking was removing older version of a file that is still in the project. I guess this info could be inferred from the chapter, but any additional info is welcomed.

Comment: And this is the reason for not providing an answer in the form of a link. It is down and now the answer is essentially as useful as a response of 'yes'

Comment: @Justin, The Progit book is freely available online. One can search for it and look at the chapter I have referenced above. Even if that link is down there are other sites from which the book is still accessible.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already, you will be re-writing history here, so you will have to get collaborators (if any) to do `git rebase`.

As for stripping a particular file from history, [Github has a nice walkthrough](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/).

For a solution going forward, you should look at putting the binary files in a sub-module.

> Git's submodule support allows a repository to contain, as a subdirectory, a checkout of an external project. Submodules maintain their own identity; the submodule support just stores the submodule repository location and commit ID, so other developers who clone the containing project ("superproject") can easily clone all the submodules at the same revision. Partial checkouts of the superproject are possible: you can tell Git to clone none, some or all of the submodules.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thanks for the information, the submodule stuff looks promising.

I already saw the Github tutorial, but the problem with it is that it just tells you "run these commands" but it doesn't tell you what are you doing exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this can't be done, because in git, every commit depends on the *contents* of the *entire* history up to that point. So the only way to get rid of the old, big files would be to "replay" the entire commit history (preferrably with the same commit timestamps and authors), omitting the big files. Note that this will produce an entirely separate commit history.

This is obviously not a very viable approach, so the lesson is probably "don't use git to version huge binary files". Instead, you could perhaps have a separate (ignored) folder for the files and use a separate system to version control them.

Comment: The important thing here is that by rewriting history, you will have separate repositories that can not longer push/pull from each other. You'll have to clone a new bare copy and over-write `origin`, and get everybody else contributing to your project to clone a fresh copy.

Comment: Aasmund: Well, most the rated answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984428/how-to-delete-the-old-history-after-running-git-filter-branch makes me think that this indeed can be done (although and I'm not 100% sure).

meagar: That would be completely OK. I just want a clear a simple manner to accomplish this (don't have the time these days to go deep into tons of Git documentation).

Comment: @meagar: True; that's what I meant by "Note that this will produce an entirely separate commit history." (it wasn't very well formulated, though.)

Comment: @rsanchez: I didn't know about `git filter-branch`, but it does indeed look like an automated version of what I suggested. Again, note that you'll end up with a history that does not overlap the old one. But if this is a personal project, that's probably okay. After the filtering, you can delete the original branch (after you're 100% sure that the filtering worked - I'd keep a copy of the original repository somewhere) and run `git gc`, which should delete the binary files that are no longer part of the history.