# Remove a deleted folder from git history

Tags: git

How can I remove a folder that is already deleted from the git history?

In my git repository I have a folder called `/foo` (1.2GB of size). I have deleted the folder `foo` with `rm -rf /foo` beause I do not need it any more. After many other commits I thought. Why is my remote repo so big...I have forgotten to do `git rm --cached ...` instead of `rm -rf ...`. How can I now remove the folder from git history?

`git rm --cached /foo` won't work because the folder is already delete in an earlier commit.

Comment: Check this question, which addresses similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358476/how-to-remove-old-versions-of-media-files-from-a-git-repository

Comment: Also, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-do-i-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-in-git-history and here http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/ ; Generally any googling about "git large file delete permanent" comes up with something about "filter-branch" utility. Never used it myself though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_examples) covers the similar case of purging a file from history:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

Since you are deleting a whole directory, add the `-r` flag to `git rm`:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
                  'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/directory' HEAD
```

Note that this operation will take several minutes on larger repositories.

More importantly, it will make a new repository with distinct history and checksums. If you previously published your repository, the history of the new one will not be compatible with the history others have pulled.

Comment: Your `filter-branch` command didn't work for me.   I found one [here](http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html) that does: `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' --prune-empty -f -- --all `

Comment: @StephenOstermiller's comment should be the answer... [the link he shared](http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html) was amazing.

Comment: The link that @StephenOstermiller shared is not  longer available , I found it in wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190106011431/http://stevelorek.com/how-to-shrink-a-git-repository.html