# How to deploy React app - paths need twitching

Tags: reactjs, build

I am an aspiring developer. I have cloned Emilio Quintanas Servitodo APP into my own repository. I downloaded the repo, and used gh-pages with npm to build and deploy the APP, but the links are not working.

When my homepage is `jsitges.github.io/` I get the error "no shallow build allowed" but when I build to `jsitges.github.io/servitodo` the paths to the app are not configured correctly.

https://github.com/jsitges/servitodo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28983842/13081108 this might help

Comment: What do you mean by "paths need twitching"?

Comment: @halfer the paths show 404, not found.  the app is deployed in /sevitodo/, but the paths in my app are set from root. it should be something quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I may have the same problem as posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748197/how-to-clone-seed-kick-start-project-without-the-whole-history), I will try later today, but to me that is the most obvious solution so far.

I am assuming I have a question regarding history,  the solution to that:

```
git clone <git_url>
```

delete the .git repository from your folder. Which will delete all your history.

The you can do a

```
git init
```

which will create an entirely new git project for you.

This may not be the best way. But this will work . Hope it helps.

So last, is the question of wether this is a valid question at all, The initial challenge was to build an app. TO THIS AVAIL, i copied emilio Quintana's app.  But did not include the API part.

NOW I have also cloned the API for his app, but how can I learn how to publish the react app along with it's API.  These are the Features he implemented:

> React Router to enable client side rendering and optimized performance.
> Utilized JSON Web Tokens and localStorage to store encrypted user information client-side.
> Developed a Rails API using a PostgreSQL database with endpoints for users, jobs and professionals.
> Implemented user interface employing React and Redux with Material UI for styling.
> Utilized Stripe Elements to enable credit card payments.

And the Tech Stack he used

> 

React & Redux and Material UI.

What does this mean? tech Stack? I infere what that means, but where can i costumize his app so that I can basically copy its inner workings and have it served from gh-pages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).